# Where is this value come from? (javascript localStorage)

Tags: javascript, php, browser, local-storage

I included this javascript file in my php web page.
I use a `if` statement to see if the value of `tried_or_not2` is `yes`.
Here is the code.

```js
let tried_or_not2 = localStorage.getItem('tried_or_not2');
form_for_login.style['visibility'] = 'visible';

console.log('test1', localStorage.getItem('tried_or_not2'));

if (tried_or_not2 !== 'yes') {
    console.log('test2');
    localStorage.setItem('tried_or_not2', 'yes');
    invitation_code.value = localStorage.getItem('invitation_code');
    password.value = localStorage.getItem('password');
    console.log('test3');
    form_for_login.submit();
    console.log('test4');
}

console.log('test5');
```

Here is the result.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/SxfB4.png

We can see `test1`, `yes` , `test5` on the console.
But when I comment the line

```js
localStorage.setItem('tried_or_not2', 'yes');
```

the value of `tried_or_not2` becomes `null`.
That means the value of `tried_or_not2` is created at that line ,right?
But, why does it print `yes` at first?
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

Unless you're clearing the localStorage before reloading, the previous values will persist. Meaning that even if you don't set the value now, the value you set previously will still be available. If you want the values to be cleared after the tab is closed, use `sessionStorage` instead. Or just clear the value after the page loads.

Comment: SessionStorage values are cleared when that browser tab is closed or the browser is closed. They will persist across reloads.

Comment: Thank you1! I understande now